# Create lines of based on same ID points

Tags: qgis, point, line

I have an excel file containing coordinates of taxi positions which I would like to turn into lines in QGIS. The example data are as follows

```
no   trj_id       lat        lng
1    10162    -6.32044    106.837
2    10162    -6.32043    106.837
3    10162    -6.32048    106.837
4    10162    -6.32054    106.8369
.      .          .           .
.      .          .           .
.      .          .           .
.      .          .           .
438  10165     -6.25062   106.9883
439  10165     -6.25068   106.9881
.      .          .           .
.      .          .           .
.      .          .           .
```

This goes on for another 377000 points with total of 471 trj_id

I have attached the points represented in QGIS as shown below
[image: Points in QGIS]

The idea is to create a line based on the same trj_id in QGIS, but I am not sure how to implement it simultaneously. I previously separate the data points based on trj_id but that would take a lot files. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Run "points to path" from [processing toolbox](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html) and set `no` as `Order field` and `trj_id` as `Group field`:

[image]

From your example, two lines were created:

[image][image]